# writing to channel in for loop skips iterations

Tags: go, channel

I am playing with channels. I have this code below which contains a for loop. I don't understand why the program seem to skip every other iteration and also why the last value is 0.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func send(c chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go send(c)
    for range c {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the golang tour first.
https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4

You use two different kind of reading in the same time:
`for range c` reads from c channel once, then you read again from the channel with `<-c`

if you would like to write out what you sent to the channel simply use one of the followings:

```
for value := range c {
  fmt.Println(value)
}

OR

for {
  select {
  case value, ok := <- c:
    if !ok {
      return
    }
    fmt.Println(value)
  }
}
```

Because you have odd number of iterations (1..5) the last 0 appears because of the read from the closed channel (default value of type).

If you use `value, ok := <-c` and the channel is closed when you read from it, the value always will be the default value and `ok` will be `false`.

Comment: Accepting this as its most complete in the explanations of all underlying aspects.

Answer (score 3):

because range take a value from the channel the correct code would look like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func send(c chan int) {
    for i := 1; i < 6; i++ {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go send(c)
    for value := range c {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that's it. I've seen that in the docs before but I somehow thought my code is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your culprit is `range c`

https://play.golang.org/p/yGrUhdLAQE-

You should not do range on `c` instead you should use infinite for loop or case statement.

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go send(c)
    for {
        d, ok:= <- c
        if !ok{
          break
        }
        fmt.Println(d)
    }
}
```

Though if you really want to use range over `c` then you should do something like this

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go send(c)
    for x := range c {
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: no. the problem is that he pulls twice from the channel. Once from the range, once to print.

Comment: the for loop will automatically exits when the channel is closed, there is no need to select in this case.

Comment: That;s true, I was just updating the answer.

Comment: or he can just assign the value in the range loop and print that value